# Select keys where value is empty /array/php

Tags: php, arrays

I have array,where is a lot of empty field. How can I remove the filled fields,and make new array with the empty fields.
So,example:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 26
            [user_type] => 2
            [user_name] => Julian
            [password] => b941da1629f4742de62796d51730edbb
            [fpassword] => 1
            [email] => akombakom@abrakadabra.dabra
            [name] => 
            [surname] => 
            [birthday] => 0000-00-00
            [country] => 
            [city] => 
            [adress] => 
            [post_code] => 
            [mob_number] => 77077412
            [tel_number] => 0
            [web_page] => 
            [registration_date] => 2016-11-19 05:03:05
            [active] => 1
            [activation_code] => 714779
            [last_login] => 2016-11-20 12:06:36
        )
```

So I want this:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [surname] => 
            [birthday] => 0000-00-00
            [country] => 
            [city] => 
            [adress] => 
            [post_code] => 
            [tel_number] => 0
            [web_page] => 

        )
```

I tired `array_diff($data, array(''));`,but nothing happend.Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this, in `$a1` - just keep rules which values you want to see in new array.

```
$a1 = array('empty' => '', 'another_rule' => '0000-00-00');
$a2 = array(
            'id' => 26,
            'user_type' => 2,
            'name' => '',
            'birthday' => '0000-00-00',
        );
$result = array_intersect($a2, $a1);
```

Comment: Working! Thx u so much!

Answer (score 3):

You need a "reverse" `array_filter`, like:

```
$empty = array_filter($data, function($item) {
    return empty($item);
});
```

But it needs to be tuned for various values, for example date `0000-00-00` is not "falsy" so it won't be caught by `empty`. The rule is that you need to return true from `array_filter`'s callable for any value that you consider "empty".

The code you need in this example will be:

```
$data = [
    'int' => 100,
    'str' => 'val',
    'empty' => '',
    'null' => null,
    'date' => '0000-00-00',
];
$empty = array_filter($data, function($item) {
    return empty($item) || '0000-00-00' === $item;
});
```